# Remove showing "Is popular" in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a client that doesn't like that SharePoint online shows[image] what users have been working on i.e. "is popular". Is there a way to remove this? I have looked through every setting. Please see screenshot as example.

Cheers.

I don't know why the image is in the middle of the paragraph, sorry.

---

I have checked each SharePoint site, this feature is already turned off.

[image]

Comment: Did given solution solved your problem? Please accept as answer it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This is showing because Reporting feature is active at site collection level.

You can disable it following below steps.

1. Go to Settings
2. Click on Site Settings->Site collection features under Site Collection Administration->scroll to Reporting feature, deactivate it.

[image: Reporting Feature]

Please accept as answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Please see above comment

Comment: turn off first one from screen shot i.e.  Reporting feature